# Firebase/React: Add record for user email if email do not exist yet

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The question has already been asked and answered several times but it seems to me that firebase has changed since that and most provided answers are not working anymore, so here I go again with this simple scenario: I have a form, where an user can input his email. Then, I'm creating a new firebase record such as:

```
-Ku_1ojtDA-3hVO6aN38
   email: "hello@world.com"
```

My main concern is to avoid duplication of same e-mail in firebase so I'm trying to 'fetch' the base and check for existing records with same value into it before posting. So far, here is the component I have made for this contact form:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const config = {
  apiKey: "**************************************",
  authDomain: "***********.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://***********.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "***********",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "***********",
};


const database = firebase
  .initializeApp(config)
  .database()

const addLocation = data => database.ref().child('users').push(data, response => response);

const updateLocation = (id, data) => database.ref().child(`users/${id}`).update(data, response => response);

const actions = {
  addLocation,
  updateLocation,
};


class Contact extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var email = this.state.value;
    // database.ref("users").orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).once("value", snapshot => {    
    database.ref().child("users").orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).once("value", snapshot => {
      const userEmail = snapshot.val();
      if (userEmail){
        console.log("user exists!");
      } else {
        addLocation({email: email});
      }
    });
    dataLayer.push({'event': 'emailAcquisition'});
  }


  render() {
    return (

            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <div className="centerpanel is-mobile">
                <div className="leftpanel" id="email-field">
                  <p className="control has-icons-left">
                    <input className="input is-large" type="email" id="email-field" placeholder="Email" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}  />
                    <span className="icon is-normal is-left">
                      <i className="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                    </span>
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div className="rightpanel" id="email-button">
                  <p className="control">
                    <input className="button is-primary is-large" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>

    );
  }
}

export default Contact;
```

Right now, I believe the problem comes from the following code not working as intended:

```
database.ref("users").orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).once(...)
```

Sorry for the noob question, any input is appreciated.

Comment: I think it should be `firebase.database().ref("users").orderByChild('email')` but I'm not sure

Comment: And a second thing. you don't need `$('input#email-field').val()` value is `this.state.value`. Try not to mix up jQuery and react as much as you can.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, I tried to replace the line with your sample but it seems like the code is still not even interpreted (console.log right after the => and the event is not even triggered). Thanks for this.state.value tho :)

Comment: any errors on console?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It's quiet as it can be. I'll keep on investigating and try to find more about this .once ('value', snapshot => ) in docs...

Comment: Try changing `const database = firebase .initializeApp(config) .database().ref();` to just `firebase .initializeApp(config)`. Assigning to a variable might not actually cause not initializing.

Comment: Finally got an error on console: Uncaught TypeError: database.child is not a function with the following code: `firebase.database().ref("users").orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).once("value", snapshot =>... `

Comment: That probably because you change the initialization of the firebase too. I think that error for the `addLocation ` or `updateLocation` parts

Comment: Good call, that was it. but code still not interpreted within the `=> ... `. What would be the way you iterate through emails to find a specific one?

Comment: I don't think problem is the query. Thats the way to go if you ask me. try `database.ref("users").orderByChild('email')` rather than `firebase.database()` with the initial code of yours.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense but I have this `database.ref is not a function` in console now. I'm initializing database this way now:
`const database = firebase
  .initializeApp(config)`

Is that correct?

Comment: I think I should call it by:
`database.database().ref("users")` ... but this doesnt trigger anything aswell.

Comment: make it same as before, like this `const database = firebase.initializeApp(config).database();` and change `database.child( )` parts to `database.ref().child( )` in your other functions

Comment: I totally udnerstand but still doesnt work. Gonna investigate tomorrow into this with the docs and try another approach. So far here is what I have:

`const database = firebase
  .initializeApp(config)
  .database()`

and 

`handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var email = this.state.value;
    database.ref("users").orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).once("value", snapshot => {
      const userEmail = snapshot.val();
      if (userEmail){
        console.log("user exists!");
      } else {
        addLocation({email: email});
      }
    });
  }`

Comment: Its hard to read. Please update your question with the new edition of your code. It will be easier to read

Comment: Edited the original code with the new one.

Comment: Did you look at me answer?

Answer (score 1):

The best and the official way to check if an email or username or any value are existing at any reference is to have additional node that stores and duplicate the email for example as follows:

```
+emails:
-------hello@world.com : true,
-------another@email.com: true
```

This way you can easily check if the an `email` variable's value that is taken form textbox or anything does exists or not by adding once listener to `emails` node then you will have the snapshot with `null` value if that email does not exist on the email node, as the following js example tested and working on my app:

```
firebase.database().ref('emails/'+ email).once('value', function (dataSnapshot) {
if(dataSnapshot.val() !== null) { 
        console.log(dataSnapshot.val());
        //the email already exists
   }
else{
       //the  email is available
}
```

And you add emails to a duplicated node just like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('emails/' + email).set(true);
```

Note that `email` variable is your variable that contains the email that you want to check it's available. 
Denormalization is normal in firebase and you have to structure your data the way you will use it in the UI. More information is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#fanout).

Comment: Keep your data structure as flat as possible

Comment: That's very interesting, I really didn't even though about this option because I'm used to SQL so much. I truly appreciate the answer and gonna test the code before marking as answered. By the way, do you have any idea how I can build the node to store the emails 'table' such as just a list of records as you are explaining in first part with firebase?

Comment: You have to spend some time to learn how to structure your data just like you spend some time doing ERDs for SQL tables. I have updated the code with how to add another node and impotent fix to the reference of the listener `ref('emails/'+ email)`.

Comment: You should also note that this way is much faster and efficient to download only the emails instead of downloading the whole information of the user

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: The current code results in:
`database-name:
   emails
     -KucgFT-JHnazWVcydm7: true
     -KucgFl2CkbwLRm_oQiz: true`

Which is not really what you had in mind right?

Comment: you are storing the key not the email. focus on my answer and store the email please.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code, problem was the way I was trying to read the base:

```
 handleSubmit(event) {
    var userEmail = this.state.value;
    event.preventDefault();
    firebase.database().ref('/users').orderByChild("email").equalTo(userEmail).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
        console.log("emails exists")
        // handle error
      } else {
        console.log("emails do not exists")
        // push record to Firebase
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: This is not efficient in firebase because you will fetch all of your data to check only for email. Follow this tutorial it will help you a lot 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SfenWGeHarE